# Active Directory prerequisites for Active Directory preparation failed

Tags: active-directory, prerequisites

I Cannot promote a new **Server 2012 R2** server to domain controller on an existing domain. The DC servers are  2008 and the new servers are server 2012
to promote the server the machine display The prerequisites check fails.
Verification of prerequisites for Active Directory preparation failed. Unable to verify whether schema master has completed a replication cycle after last reboot.

```
Exception: Unavailable Critical Extension. Server extended error: 8366. Server extended message: 000020AE: SvcErr: DSID-03210384, problem 5010 (UNAVAIL_EXTENSION), data 8610
.
Adprep failed to verify whether schema master has completed a replication cycle after last reboot.
[Status/Consequence]
The schema is not upgraded.
[User Action]
Check the log file ADPrep.log in the C:\Windows\debug\adprep\logs\20170227024251-test directory for possible cause of failure.
```

Answer (score 0):

You need perform [schema update](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd464018(v=ws.10).aspx) (it can do anyone who is *Enterprise Admins* group memeber).
This error may happens, if you do not have the required permissions in the forest.